# Notation for some general pde for biological equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, notation

Recently, I was reading the article ["Simulating Spatial Differenetial Equations with Cellular Automata"](http://www.r2labs.org/pubs/strader-biocomp09.pdf). On page 2, there is a general form that is said to hold for most biological ODE equations, namely:
$$
f(u_{i,j})=\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=m(u_{i,j})+\nabla_x^2 n(u_{i,j})+\nabla_x o(u_{i,j})~~~(4).
$$

When I see it right, we have that $u=u(t,x)$ is a function of time $t$ and one dimensional space $x$.

So I really do not understand what is meant by the notation $u_{i,j}$, i.e. with time index $i$ and space index $j$.

Moreover, if $x$ is representing one-dimensional space, why don't we just write 
$$
\nabla_x^2 n(u_{i,j})=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}n(u_{i,j}),\qquad\nabla_x o(u_{i,j})=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}o(u_{i,j})?
$$

Comment: The paper is about _simulating_ some biological problems on a computer. The $i$ and $j$ indices are referring to the $i^{th}$ time step and $j^{th}$ grid point, which comes from discretising the PDE in both time and space. If this doesn't make sense to you, I suggest reading up on numerics.

Comment: Hence $u_{i,j}=u(ih,jk)$ for some time- resp. space discretization?

Comment: For step sizes $h$ and $k$, yes.

Comment: Okay and the next step then is to replace the derivatives (f.e. by euler scheme) right?

Comment: The first case they use forward Euler (difference) for the time derivatives, central difference on the gradient term and first order backward difference on the Laplacian. I haven't read through the rest of the paper for the other numerical schemes used.